# How to give strokes a specific width based on base64

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to build a stroked line, based on a svg file, cause of the color and the corner shapes that it has. Each stroke is `15px` wide and has a gap between each line from also `15px`. The problem is that when i try to include it via `background-image` it always makes the line longer than it actually should be.

```css
.stroke-dotted {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="stroke-dotted"></div>
```

**Thats how it should look like:**

[image]

**And that's how it looks now:**

[image]

Is there a way to give the lines a specific width of `15px` and also an gap of `15px`? I also tried to fix it with the `background-size` attribute, but it didn't worked out.

Comment: Your svg file does not have a gap that I can see. Have you created it using some software like adobe illustrator or sketch? In that case there is usually an option to include artbord. That settig keeps the empty space in place and embedds it into the svg.

Comment: i created it via sketch. Basicly the agency http://bb.agency used it to.They got the effect on their website also. They got many lines, but the the svg includes only one stroke, so not the whole dashed stroke wich was designed in sketch or illustrator

Comment: I see. If you open up `data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0...` in a browser tab you can inspectit and see for yourself.
I would suggest solving this with pure css or inline svg perhaps. But that is not your question though.

Comment: You can eventually resize the stroke via vw , give a try to `stroke-width="0.2vw"` if that is big enough.(within the svg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: don't encode your SVG as a base64, it is *much* longer than the original code and its unnecessary as you can just add the code to the url. You might need to URL encode it for IE11 and earlier, but otherwise all browsers support it.

Now, to control your sizing in SVG tags, *ommit* the `viewBox` and simply give it a width and height of `100%` and express all other values in percentage. Now you can control the size of the line by defining its pixel size, even though the points are defined in percentage:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\
    <line x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="1px" stroke-dasharray="15px 15px" />\
  </svg>') no-repeat 50% 50% / cover;
}
body {
  /* A reference grid */
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width="15px" height="15px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="#222" stroke-width="1px" fill="black" />\
  </svg>');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Once your SVG is correctly set up, it is as simple as defining the `stroke-dasharray` property with the pixel values:

```
<line x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px" stroke-dasharray="15px 15px" />
```

Now you can use CSS to change your box, or even SVG to change the offsets within the SVG background.